# If a spell is twinned, does the caster need to provide costly material components for each target?

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting, metamagic

The Divine Soul Sorcerer can gain access to the *revivify* spell pretty easily (along with other costly resurrection spells), which has a costly material component that the spell consumes (300 gp worth of diamonds).

If after a particularly rough battle, can the Sorcerer use *revivify* on two separate creatures who have died for the cost of just 300 gp worth of diamonds or would it require 600 gp worth?

For the sake of this question, assume that a dead creature is a creature and not an object. If it helps, you could consider the *stoneskin* spell as well.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Twinned Spell simply lets you *target* a second creature; it doesn't make you *cast* the spell twice. This is specifically stated in its description:

> [...] target a second creature in range **with the same spell**...

Therefore you are only casting the spell once and only have to provide the material components once.

And, even though Mike Mearls and (his) tweets aren't official rulings, I think Mike describes it simply but concisely [in a tweet on a related subject](https://twitter.com/SymphFan/status/506906996684390400):

> One spell instance, two targets.

Comment: An interesting extension to this answer (or perhaps a new question) might be to discuss whether there are any twinnable spells that interact with their components in such a way that would be ambiguous when twinned.

Comment: To save money on raising the dead, just kill your local zealot and twin the raise dead spell on them and your friend (YMMV)

Comment: I think the greatest shenanigan potential is twinning Imprisonment on two people who don't like each other.

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson I definitely think that would be worth it own question.

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson Warding Bond would be an excellent spell to bring into question for ambiguity, though a cursory look shows that people have been confused on that one for a while

Comment: @Daveman thematically having the zealot drag you back from the afterlife is pretty cool.

Comment: @Daveman Warrior of the Gods specifically says "the sole effect" of the spell must be to revive the Zealot. Unfortunately, twinning Revivify likely makes it no longer meet that requirement. It's vague enough it'd probably be down to DM Fiat though.

Comment: All high level parties need to make sure they are friends with a Divine Soul, the cost of those True Resurrections is significant and we gotta cut costs!

Comment: @Pyrotechnical: Or a lvl17 cleric or druid with a sorc 3 multiclass, so they can prepare True Res for rare occasions, not having it in their limited spells-known permanently.  Or the Metamagic Adept feat, but twinning a 9th-level spell would require 9 sorcery points, so they'd still need a sorc2 multiclass to be able to convert slots into points because the feat doesn't give you Font of Magic: Flexible Casting.