# Does the Zealot Barbarians Warrior of the Gods feature work with Divine Soul Twinned Spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, barbarian

I have been looking at Xanathar's Guide to Everything, and I have a question about how the Zealot Barbarian's Warrior of the Gods feature works with Twinned Spell for a Divine Soul Sorcerer. The Warrior of the Gods feature says:

> If a spell, such as *raise dead*, has the sole effect of restoring you to life (but not undeath), the caster doesn't need material components to cast the spell on you.

So my question is:
How does Twinned spell and similar effects work with the Warrior of the Gods feature? Would the spell require material components?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### The Warrior of the Gods feature would no longer apply because you are no longer the sole target of the spell

The features states:

> If a spell, such as raise dead, has the sole effect of restoring you to life (but not undeath), the caster doesn't need material components to cast the spell on you.

However, if a ressurection spell is Twinned such that it now targets both you and another creature, the spell no longer has the *sole* effect of restoring you to life. It would *also* be restoring another creature to life, and thus this feature would not activate.

Comment: Something bugs me: the WotG feature says "if it has the sole effect of restoring you to life" but then refers to Raise Dead as an example of a valid spell for WotG. Raise Dead has the additional effect of curing non-magical disease & poison which seems to contradict the "sole effect" limitation. It seems to me that there is some gray area around the meaning of "sole effect." Might that gray area allow for some wiggle room on twinning? I'm imagining an interpretation that allows a caster to use a single instance of materials to resurrect a zealot barbarian and one other character.

Comment: @Rykara according to this question https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/181190/if-a-spell-is-twinned-does-the-caster-need-to-provide-costly-material-component that ruling is correct.

Comment: No I absolutely agree with you. That was my first take as well. I just started thinking about the possibility of alternative interpretations given the confusion around Raise Dead and "sole effect." But I also found [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/150442/48793) which addresses that.

Comment: Yes, I think WOTC was unclear with "sole effect." It may be too late for this, but I hope for some errata to clear that up and better specification (maybe a table like XGTE has for Wild Shape?).